# vld_x86 dll not found error shown when i try to run the debug mode of the application

Tags: visual-c++

i am new in using the Visual Leak Detector, after creating the settings as per the documentations for Visual C++ 6, and running the program in the debug mode
the error 
"The application has failed to start because vld_x86.dll was not found.Re-installing the application may fix this problem"

i have reinstalled and included the path for the dll in the VC6 settings.

thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: First of all why are you still using the ancient VC6? Also, is the `vld_x86.dll` present in your system?

Comment: well, i have no choice, this is what is given to me at work.the dll is present the in my system.does anybody know where to add the path in the settings

Comment: ok..I think vld_x86.dll has something to do with visual leak detector which you shouldn't be linking against. You can check which of your dependent dlls are linking against it by using this tool http://www.dependencywalker.com/ . Open your debug exe in this tool and check who is linking against the above mentioned dll.

Comment: thanks Naveen. does the placement of the header #include "vld.h" affect the functionality.

Answer (score 3):

After searching for the answer myself for quite a long time, two things finally corrected the problem for me. First, if you haven't already restarted Visual Studio after including these new files and libraries, then you should do so. Second, when I went to look into my computer to see what was added to my path in environment variables, it had add the win64. and I run win32. Hope that was descriptive enough and helps.

Comment: If that solved your question, then please accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

the include is correct and needed as far as i know.

i was having the same problem and could solve it by copying all files in vld's "bin" directory into the same folder as the executable i wanted to check for leaks.

not a very elegant way but working, i hope it works for you aswell!